# No servlet name in URL when trying to run Eclipse project

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I'm running my web app, and when I choose "run on server" I get this error in the browser:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ServletsJSPExample/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /ServletsJSPExample/

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

The URL should be like:

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletsJSPExample/Serv1
```

but it is

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletsJSPExample/
```

Just to be clear, everything is fine when I write down the address myself, but I want it to be already there when I run my app.

And here is my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ServletsJSPExample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ServletExample</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.tutorial.ServletExample</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is servlet class file:

```
package com.example.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello Java");
    }


}
```

I'm using Tomcat 7 and Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Looks like you're not closing the resources e.g. `out.close();`. Also, try changing the `service` method for `doGet`.

Comment: I did that, and it didn't help.

Comment: Wait, your problem appears when you write `http://localhost:8080/ServletsJSPExample/` in your URL bar?

Comment: Yes, but that is also the address that is automatically put in the url bar when I run my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Define a welcome file in your web.xml file:

   ```xml
   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>Serv1</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   ```
2. Create an empty file called Serv1 (no extension) in the root context of your web application project. This is because the welcome file must be a physical file in the folder structure. The application server will process the GET request for `http://localhost:8080/ServletsJSPExample/Serv1` against your servlet. Folder structure example:

   ```
   + ServletsJSPExample
     + src
       <your source packages...>
     + webapp
       - Serv1
       <other files and folders...>
   ```

---

Apart from this, it would be better to implement `doGet` and `doPost` methods instead of `service` so you could handle different business logic for each HTTP method.

Comment: According to specs (Servlet 2.4, SRV.9.10) "The Web
server must append each welcome file in the order specified in the deployment descriptor to the partial request and check whether a static resource or servlet in the WAR is mapped to that request URI." Therefore the empty file should not be required.

Comment: Then it violates the spec.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos give it a try.

Comment: A try is irrelevant. If it works this way, it violates the spec, period. I do not have Tomcat 7 available but, FYI, it *works as I wrote* on JBoss 7.1.1.

Comment: Well, did you give it a try then?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yes I did, and looks like OP also did it.

Comment: Well it works *without* any files for me. I understand that for some reason the file may be required (though I cannot see it in my case) but my comment was about *the specs*. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can add a welcome file:

```
<welcome-file>Serv1</welcome-file>
```

This approach will use the welcome file for all directories, e.g. if you have a directory `foo/bar`, the user requests `http://server/ServletsJSPExample/foo/bar/` and there is nothing mapped directly to that, the container will also try `http://server/ServletsJSPExample/foo/bar/Serv1`.

2) You can also add a mapping from `/` to `ServletExample`, in addition to the mapping form `Serv1`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But this will make it the "default servlet", i.e. it will serve all URLs not explicitly mapped to another resource or servlet. It is OK if take account of it in the code.

3) You can create an `index.jsp` in the root folder that does a redirection:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("Serv1"); %>
```

Please do note there is no leading slash, i.e. the URL is relative. In this case there will be *2 requests* (the original and the redirection) and the URL in the browser will change accordingly.

Or the JSP can do a forward:

```
<jsp:forward page="Serv1" />
```

In this case there is a single request and the URL in the browser remains the same.

Comment: See [related bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47378) and why solution (1) may not work, though it should according to specs.