# Web-app: welcome-file-list not working using servlet-mapping

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

When visiting the bare url (e.g., `localhost:8080`), I want the same behavior as visiting `localhost:8080/foo`. A servlet (actually a JSP) is mapped to `/foo`. My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <description></description>

    <!-- servlets -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/test/welcome.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet> 

    <!-- mappings -->
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/foo</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

When I do `http://localhost:8080/foo`, I get the correct output; the output of `test/welcome.jsp` is displayed. However, when visiting the bare url `http://localhost:8080`, jetty displays the file list and Tomcat 6 gives a page not found. Is my `web.xml` correct?

(versions: jetty-8.0.y.z-SNAPSHOT, Tomcat 6, Java 1.6, servlet-api-2.5)

**Changing `<welcome-file>/foo</welcome-file>` to `<welcome-file>foo</welcome-file>` makes no difference.**

Is there a mistake in my web.xml? If not, what is the right way to do what I want.

EDIT: Seems to be a bug in Jetty-8. It started working in Jetty-9.

Comment: This ought to work according to specs (Servlet 2.4, SRV.9.10) BUT there is some confusion and a related [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47378) (see the discussion of the bug). A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800640) came up a few days ago and somebody suggested a workaround, check it out.

Comment: I've always thought that welcome-file should be a file, not an url.

Comment: Strangely, the problem disappeared with Jetty-9.

Answer (score 3):

remove `/` from this         `<welcome-file>/foo</welcome-file>`
It should be

```
<welcome-file>foo</welcome-file>
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that this makes no difference.

Comment: @Jus12 when you are typing localhost:8080 then you are opening tomcat manager where you can find all the apps that are present in tomcat/webapps folder.

Comment: I deployed it on a PaaS cloud running tomcat (cloudfoundry), Locally I use jetty.

Comment: @Jus12 I am not having much knowldge about cloud but there is an alternate which i do not suggest you to do.So when you are typing localhost:8080 then it opens tomcat manager because its mentioned in web.xml of the tomcat(should not be confused with the web.xml of your app).The reason why i do not suggest you because it will open directly your app and wont ask for username and password which manager used to do.Well if you tell me why you directly want to access to your app by typing localhost:8080 then I(we) can find an alternate solution

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this also works in Jetty 8 (you should probably update anyway), but in Jetty 9 you can put the following code in your web.xml to enable Servlets as welcome files for Jetty:

```
<!-- Enable servlets as welcome files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>
       org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.welcomeServlets
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See this docs:
http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>foo</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Here's a good explanation:
http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/HowToUseAServletAsYourMainWebPage